ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybaseball'
I am in the process of trying to learn python. I installed the 'pybaseball' package using the pip command in my virtual environment. I cannot import the package because I receive a module not found error. The package is installed in this location on my mac: /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages. The path to my current project file is :
/Users/tyler/Desktop/Python:SQL/Baseball_Data/.venv/bin/python /Users/tyler/Desktop/Python:SQL/Baseball_Data/Pitchers.py.
Can I please have assistance with fixing this?
I have this missing module error with other packages that I have installed as well.
Python3 and pip3 are in the same homebrew folder
/opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
/opt/homebrew/bin/python3

When I try to install the pybaseball package inside of the activated virtual environment's terminal with the pip or pip3 command, it gets downloaded to the homebrew folder and I cannot import the module:
/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages

I am using VS Code.

Is your virtual environment activated when importing the package?

It seems that you installed the package into wrong path. You can use which python command in VSCode terminal to check which python interpreter you are currently using. For your project, you have to ensure the venv is enabled before installing packages with pip.
Activate the venv inside/Users/tyler/Desktop/Python:SQL/Baseball_Data/.venv/bin/python and installing the packages with pip3 install pybaseball, then you should be good to go.
